# Setting up Apache permissions properly

Tags: apache, permissions, http-status-code-403

Here's my understanding of the correct way to set up website permissions:

- Ownership of all directories and files in /home/website is website:website
- All directories are 0750
- All files are 0640
- apache is a member of the group "website" (as one of apache's secondary groups)

But it isn't working- I'm getting 403 errors with `(13)Permission denied: /home/website/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable`.

Not sure what is going on, as apache should be able to read everything, since it is in the "website" group.

One other thing of note is that there is no .htaccess in /home/website; it is in /home/website/public_html, so I'm not even really sure what is going on with the logs (The VirtualHost does point to the public_html directory).

Any ideas? If I set everything to 755/644 it works, but that is what I'm trying to avoid. This seems to indicate apache isn't actually in the "website" group, but I checked Webmin many times; "website" is in fact one of apache's secondary groups.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

And did you update your Apache config to set the runtime group to 'website' (/etc/apache2/uid.conf on the machine in front of me) then restart it?

(Personally I usually give my webserver access to files as 'other' which simplifies deployment. Do you have users on your system who are not allowed to see the webserver files?)

Comment: No, the group is set in the conf to "apache." Hesitant to change that as it could cause problems in other places, unless there can be more than one "Group" directive. Also I'd need to set this up for multiple sites/users on the server. We have customers FTP'ing in now, and need to prevent them from reading each others files.

Comment: Could cause problems? That is what *is* causing your current problem. You need to fit the permissions around your security model - and its very hard to imagine what the security model fits the scenario you've just described and the permissions in your original question.

Comment: Well, I got it working with "usermod -a -G apache website". Must have been doing something wrong trying to do that through webmin. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

/home/website needs to be searchable (executable) by the httpd userid.  Apache is failing to search for the existence of an htaccess file because it's missing those bits.

Described in detail here: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied